# Excel Function Difference Between Two Dates

Tags: excel, function, vba, date

I need to create an Excel Function which giving to times (entry time and exiting time), it calculates the time (hh:mm) between these two, for example if the employee entries at 23:00 (11pm), and exits at 07:00 (7am), it should write 8:00 in the cell.
The reason that I'm not using time subtract is because of cases like the one in the previous example, as it will give and error (7am is lower than 11pm).
So far, I wrote the following code:

```
Function DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS(ByVal EntryTime As Date, ByVal ExitTime As Date)
Dim hexit, hentry, mexit, mentry, dminutes, dhours As Integer
hexit = Int(Hour(ExitTime))
hentry = Int(Hour(EntryTime))
mentry = Int(Minute(EntryTime))
mexit = Int(Minute(ExitTime))
If ExitTime < EntryTime Then
    If mexit < mentry Then
        dhours = (hexit + 24) - hentry
        dminutes = (mexit + 60) - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = Time(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    Else
        dhours = (hexit + 24) - hentry
        dminutes = mexit - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = Time(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    End If
Else
    If mexit < mentry Then
        dhours = hexit - hentry
        dminutes = (mexit + 60) - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = Time(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    Else
        dhours = hexit - hentry
        dminutes = mexit - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = Time(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    End If
End If
```

End Function

But this gives me a #VALUE error in the cell.
Thanks a lot for your attention, and if you need more info to help me, please request and I will provide you.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change time() with timeserial()

```
Function DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS(ByVal EntryTime As Date, ByVal ExitTime As Date)
Dim hexit, hentry, mexit, mentry, dminutes, dhours As Integer
hexit = Int(Hour(ExitTime))
hentry = Int(Hour(EntryTime))
mentry = Int(Minute(EntryTime))
mexit = Int(Minute(ExitTime))
If ExitTime < EntryTime Then
    If mexit < mentry Then
        dhours = (hexit + 24) - hentry
        dminutes = (mexit + 60) - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = TimeSerial(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    Else
        dhours = (hexit + 24) - hentry
        dminutes = mexit - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = TimeSerial(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    End If
Else
    If mexit < mentry Then
        dhours = hexit - hentry
        dminutes = (mexit + 60) - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = TimeSerial(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    Else
        dhours = hexit - hentry
        dminutes = mexit - mentry
        DIFERENCAHORASMINUTOS = TimeSerial(dhours, dminutes, 0)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a formula you can use

=MOD(B2-A2,1)

Comment: Thanks also for simplifying my problem.